# Delete Rows based on Date criteria from second sheet and Paste in New Rows from third sheet

Tags: vba, copy-paste

ok i'm new to macros but I'm decent at understanding so have gotten a fair amount of simple stuff done recently.  mostly off amending recorded macros.

let me explain my file. i don't know how to add spaces or borders in here and i just spent like 10 minutes googling that.  anyway, there are 3 columns: Report Date, Section, and CUSIP.

**Sheet 2**

```
Report Date | Section       | CUSIP
-----------------------------------
8/30/2019   | US Sales      | XYZ
8/30/2019   | US Sales      | ABC
8/30/2019   | Foreign Sales | 123
8/30/2019   | Foreign Sales | 456
8/30/2019   | Foreign Sales | 789
8/30/2019   | Foreign Sales | 1011
7/30/2019   | Foreign Sales | 1213
7/30/2019   | US Sales      | EFG
7/30/2019   | US Sales      | HIJ
7/30/2019   | US Sales      | KLM
7/30/2019   | US Sales      | NO14
7/30/2019   | Foreign Sales | 1516P
```

In cell A1 of **Sheet_1**, there is a Date i want to reference to. 
For this example, let's say **Sheet_1** A1 = 9/30/2019.

Now, i need the macro to look at the data in **Sheet_2** Column A and delete every single row that has a date older than my reference Date by at least two months.

So, if my reference date in **Sheet_1** A1 is 9/30/2019, then I need every line deleted on **Sheet_2** that has the date of 7/29/2019 or before that.

There are thousands of rows of data. So, what would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Also, each month's data will likely be blocked together in groups...meaning i won't have alternating rows of one month to another.

Essentially, this is just removing data that is 2 months old from the sheet.

After it's done with that, i need the macro to go to **Sheet_3**, and copy the data from row 2, until the last row that has data in it.  next, it then pastes values into the first blank row of data in **Sheet_2**.

Hopefully that is clear.  Basically, in other words, I have a sheet that has two months of data in it.  As indicated by the Date in column A.  Each month, I need to go to this sheet, remove the data that is two months old, and paste in the data that is new (aka the value in cell A1 of Sheet_1).

any help is appreciated

Comment: Is everything new data on Sheet_3? So do you want to import everything from Sheet_3? What about sorting it? What makes your Sheet_2 data sorted? You said different dates are "grouped" together, I guess you meant sorted? So is your Sheet_2 table Sorted by date?

Comment: hi Andras.  so the data on Sheet_3 contains the most recent month's data.  so it would only contain data for 9/30/19 in this example.  

yes, import everything from Sheet_3, except the headers, so takes the data from row 2 until the last row of data.

yes, Sheet_2 table is sorted by data.  so you'll have like 400 rows of data for 8/30/19, and then 400 rows of data for 7/30/19

Comment: would really appreciate learning how to do this.  I have a few instances where I need to copy/paste based on values and I'm not keen enough to pick it up off whatever I googled...

Comment: I spotted a problem in the code, but it is all good now... If you have tried it already, then please delete it from your Workbook and add it again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll see if we got the details right...

I would probably only test this on a **copy** of your real Workbook...

(I am sure it is obvious to you as well, but I Just Couldn't Not Say It.)

So here it is:

```
Option Explicit ' I Wouldn't go without this...
' It will demand you to declare every variable you use.
' ... without that you may not know why you are having problems...

Sub DataHandling()
    Dim Number_Of_Days_To_Keep As Integer
    Dim Reference_Date_Sht_Name As String
    Dim Data_Store_Sheet_Name As String
    Dim New_Data_Sheet_Name As String

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Set the number of days, of which data you want to keep...
    Number_Of_Days_To_Keep = 60

    ' Set Sheet Names
    Reference_Date_Sht_Name = "Sheet1"
    Data_Store_Sheet_Name = "Sheet2"
    New_Data_Sheet_Name = "Sheet3"
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ' Set Reference Variable to your Workbook
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Set WB = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    ' Set Reference Variables to Worksheets
    Dim RefDateSht As Worksheet
    Dim DataStoreSht As Worksheet
    Dim NewDataSht As Worksheet
    Set RefDateSht = WB.Worksheets(Reference_Date_Sht_Name)
    Set DataStoreSht = WB.Worksheets(Data_Store_Sheet_Name)
    Set NewDataSht = WB.Worksheets(New_Data_Sheet_Name)

    ' Reference Date from Reference Date Sheet
    Dim RefDate As Date
    RefDate = CDate(RefDateSht.Cells(1, "A").Value)

    ' Calculate Cut Off Date from Reference Date and Number Of Days To Keep
    Dim CutOffDate As Date
    CutOffDate = DateAdd("d", -(Number_Of_Days_To_Keep + 1), RefDate)

    ' Last DataStore Row and the DataStore Range
    Dim LastDSRow As Long
    Dim DSRng As Range
    LastDSRow = DataStoreSht.Cells(DataStoreSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set DSRng = DataStoreSht.Range(DataStoreSht.Cells(2, "A"), DataStoreSht.Cells(LastDSRow, "X"))

    ' Last NewData Row and the NewData Range
    Dim LastNDRow As Long
    Dim NDRng As Range
    LastNDRow = NewDataSht.Cells(NewDataSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set NDRng = NewDataSht.Range(NewDataSht.Cells(2, "A"), NewDataSht.Cells(LastNDRow, "X"))

    ' Support Reference Variables
    Dim Celll As Range
    Dim FirstCutOffCell As Range

    ' Let's see if the Cut Off Date exists in Column 1 of DataStoreSht ...
    Set FirstCutOffCell = DSRng.Columns(1).Cells.Find(What:=Format(CutOffDate, "m/dd/yy"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If FirstCutOffCell Is Nothing Then
        ' ... if it does not, then check every Row until the Cut Off point is found
        For Each Celll In DSRng.Columns(1).Cells
            If Celll.Value < CutOffDate Then
                Set FirstCutOffCell = Celll
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    ' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Delete the block of lines which have date before the Cut Off date
    ' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    If Not FirstCutOffCell Is Nothing Then
        With DataStoreSht
            .Rows(FirstCutOffCell.Row & ":" & LastDSRow).EntireRow.Delete
            LastDSRow = .Cells(DataStoreSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Set DSRng = .Range(DataStoreSht.Cells(2, 1), DataStoreSht.Cells(LastDSRow, 3))
        End With
    End If

    ' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' If there is any New Data on NewDataSht then ...
    ' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    If LastNDRow > 1 Then
        ' ... move New Data from NewDataSht to Second Line of DataStoreSht by shifting existing data down.
        NDRng.Copy
        DataStoreSht.Rows(2).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: one more note: no data should be removed from Sheet_3, only copied from.  I am only deleting data from Sheet_2

Comment: Now then, I thought Sheet_3 would only ever have have new data... Isn't that so?

Comment: Your model of data on Sheet_2 only contained the first three columns... Report Date, Section, and CUSIP. Is there more to copy from Sheet_3 to Sheet_2?

Comment: can you also arrange this so it pastes values?

aside from those two things, I love this thing...thank you so much

Comment: hi Andras:
1.  correct, Sheet_3 only have new data.  I want this data copy/pasted values into Sheet_2.  But I do not want it removed from Sheet_3.  both sheets will contain the data at the end of the paste
2.  I just changed it to deal with 23 columns rather than 3 columns...was proud of myself for fixing that

Comment: to be clear, only Sheet_2 will have data deleted from it.  this is the tab that will eventually contain outdated data

Comment: getting an error at the sorting by descending date on this line:

.SortFields.Add2 Key:=DSRng.Columns(1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

"run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Sorry but I am a bit confused, if you never delete from Sheet_3 then how does it only contain New Data..? It contains absolutely everything from the beginnings, doesn't it? In that case how do I know what part of it to copy over to Sheet_2 as New Data?

Comment: hey Andras, sorry I wasn't clear....

so this is just a portion of an overall task.  I have a couple other macros in my file that accomplish different things at different points.

for the purposes of this macro, I only need it to reference Sheet_2 to know what to paste values of into Sheet_3.  does that make sense?

also, copy everything in sheet two from Row 2, until the last row of data

Comment: Not completely, but it doesn't matter I don't need to know...  SO the changes you need are: 1., Copy and Paste instead of Cut and Paste from Sheet_3 to Sheet_2?   |  2., Exactly which Columns need to do Copy and Paste on (instead of just A,B and C)?   | 3., You also said you had an error: "Object doesn't support this property or method" at the sorting? ----------------  Are these all the changes you need?

Comment: hi Andras, 
1.  Copy and Paste Values. 
2.  Columns A thru X
3.  Correct on the error.

thank you very much again

Comment: I believe the error will be down to a different version of Office because at my end everything was perfectly fine... I have Office 2016, what version of Office do you have?

Comment: ah interesting.  I have office 2013.
no worries on that then, not a priority for me...(I may end up deleting the filter thing, as it should be unnecessary if the code acts correctly)

Comment: poorly chosen words...the way the data is arranged and since the copy/pastes are done in blocks, every month's data is going to always stay together, so really no need to filter....(at least that's what I'm thinking)

Comment: I updated the code... there is no sorting... no cut and paste... Columns from A to X get handled....

Comment: Again, this must be something about the a difference between 2013 and 2016 because here it is fine... Does it work if you replace that line with this: `DataStoreSht.Rows(2).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown` or with this: `DataStoreSht.Rows(2).Insert xlShiftDown` or this: `DataStoreSht.Rows(2).Insert Shift:= xlDown` ?

Comment: They all properly do the on thing I want on my PC... no errors.

Comment: Does anything get deleted?

Comment: Have you used Debugging before when you step through the code line by line... and then you may get a clue why the errors are happening... also you can watch the workwheet to see as lines get deleted, and then pasted in?

Comment: I don't know what to say... how ever I am twisting the code, it works perfectly fine here... without seeing what is happening there I can't even guess anymore... Also I haven't changed the code where your old data gets deleted... so I don't know what may have suddenly caused that part not to work...

Comment: ok, i sorted it out...it looks like it works perfectly.  thank you very very much for the help, this was a great learning experience for me.  sorry for any communication issues...appreciate your time and effort

Comment: lastly, i am a fan of how cleanly you code.  do you have any youtube channels you like that go over vba? no worries if not

Comment: I haven't used YouTube much for learning, but I read an awful lot of other peoples codes, get to understand it, then change it how I need it to perform.. It would be a big help for you if you searched Youtube to see how people VBA Debugging...

Comment: well, not sure what specifically, but i changed it to go to column X to W , ( i told you to go to X cause i wanted to see how the code worked in my own way and was factoring in future amendments to my file); also saw i needed to go to B1, not A1; and i think thats it...(i renamed the worksheets properly)

Comment: will do on the youtube debugging, thanks...i typically work off of recorded macros right now and try to edit those, but i really want to set aside the time to properly code in a clean and efficient way

Comment: again, this was very helpful to me.  sorry i'm not too familiar with how to explain what i'm looking to get done...thanks again man..see ya

Comment: Well I almost offered you to try to help you by remote controlling your PC from here... to find out what the heck was going on..

Comment: hahahah nice...what program do you use to remote? that's something i could make use of with my parents..

Comment: Thanks, I hope it really helped... At the top of my Answer there is an Up Arrow (UpVote) a Down Arrow (DownVote) an the Number between them showing the actual result of the votes, and below all of them the Tick Mark to accept the Answer... Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199791/discussion-on-answer-by-andras-dorko-delete-rows-based-on-date-criteria-from-sec).